# Adding Edittext & Imagebutton dynamically in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to add and Edit text, Image button and another edit text below first one (all 3 as one item) dynamically in fragment. Initially I need to have 2 such items and an add button. When the add button is clicked I need to add all 3(2 edittext and 1 imagebutton) added below existing 2 and so on.

I tried adding single edittext to start with and its being added but its taking the whole screen layout as the layout params are specified as wrap_content. below is the code I used to add edit text:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.options_layout);
        EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());

        final int i = 2;
        editText.setId(i);
        editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        editText.setText("Hello");
        Log.d("View","Start");
        try{
               ll.addView(editText);
        }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Problem is that edittext is spanning full screen, width wise whereas I need it to be 70% and rest for Imagebutton. Also I need another edit text below this one. I tried doing with ListView creating a listitem as single piece with all 3 items but got stuck as we need to specify the count for listView. And in my case its to be added only when add button is clicked. I have been struggling quite a while but unable to get thorugh. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use weight
```

=============

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = newLinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  p.weight = .3;

  editText.setLayoutParams(p);
```